# Ace.js Programmatically add a new line

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I'm having a bit of a hard time inserting a new line programmatically with javascript.

Let me tell you a bit about my project. Firstly its meant to be an online collaborative IDE using ACE.JS and SignalR to allow near realtime editting by more then one person.

To achieve this I've hooked in to the ace.js editors change event:

```
  editor.getSession().on('change', function (e) {});
```

I then listen to the action that the user has performed and act accordingly using a switch statement. So the on change event looks like this

```
 editor.getSession().on('change', function (e) {
            console.log(self.fromserver);
            if (self.wasMe) {
                self.wasMe = false;
                return;
            }
            switch(e.data.action) {  //what action did this user perform?
                case "insertText":
                    if (!self.fromserver) {//to prevent an 'n' event loop, check if event came from server

                    } else {

                    }

                    break;
                case "insertLines":

                    if (!self.fromserver) {                    


                    } else {

                    }
                    break;
                case "removeText":

                        var position = JSON.stringify(e.data.range);
                        if (!self.fromserver) {
                            self.ide.server.removeSyntax(position); 
                        } else {
                            self.fromserver = false;
                        }

                        break;
                case "removeLines":
                    var lines = JSON.stringify(e.data.range);
                    if (!self.fromserver) {
                        self.ide.server.removeLines(lines);
                    }
                    break;
            }
            self.fromserver = false;
            console.log(e.data);
        });
```

Inserting text, pasting text in and removing text (plus removing blocks of text) work correctly.

**The problem**

New lines with indentation! Take for example a user has typed the following code:

```
function(){
```

when a user hits enter, the code block is formatted like so:

```
function(){
    //indentation 
}
```

The change events that caused this are sent to the server so that other users are updated, the server calls a function on the client machines depending on the user action. This can be either `editor.session.insert //add text` or `editor.session.remove //remove text` 
or (currently), for new lines `self.editor.insertNewLine(range.end.row, line);`

The problem is, the client machines that are updated from the server don't tab correctly, this causes their editor to become out of sync.

**The question**

My question to you guys is, does the ace.js editor have a 'format' function? I tried the editor.indent function, but that didn't seem to work properly.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my case, i have each line a unique hidden integer number generated by the Server, when updated, i send this number to all clients together with the line in string format which include the indent and line break..... everything of that line!

also, i stored those lines in sql so that when a client is offline, it will get the latest when online again.

Comment: Thank you Kenneth, I believe I'll need to rethink the information I send to the server. but this seems like the best way to do it (keeps everyone in sync with the server, doesn't let the editor assume input). So thanks. 

Jay

Comment: remember to add another hidden number, the display order, as well, e.g. in case user add a line between line 2 and line 3